# How do I change my Table of Contents to look like this?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

The deadline for my final senior design report is a few weeks away and I'm trying to migrate away from Word (which I used to finish my previous reports) to Latex. I have most of the formatting done, but despite spending several hours, I'm not able to get the Table Of Contents formatting correct. Does anyone know how I can go about making my ToC look like this?

[image: Sample ToC]

The above is a picture from my preliminary report. The final report has specifications exactly the same as the one listed above.

The closest I've gotten is by using this:

```
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
%Formatting of the TOC
\makeatletter
\renewcommand
\tableofcontents
{
  \begin{center}
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{12pt}{28.8pt}\selectfont
  \textbf{CONTENTS}
  \endgroup
  \\~\\
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother
```

However, this doesn't fix the Section-SubSection-SubSubSection indentation  and formatting issues.

As far as non-obvious formatting restrictions go, I'm required to have 2 (1.5 spaced) lines between the title (i.e. "CONTENTS") and the first two headers (i.e. "TABLES" and "FIGURES") and a one-line (1.5 spaced) space between "FIGURES" and the start of the remainder of the ToC.

Help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The indentation should be there automatically, as far as I know...

Comment: Welcome, personally, i wouldn't spend time to convert a document to LaTeX and force it to look like a Word document. I would just stick to Word.

Comment: Are the sections really numbered 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc? Would 1, 2, 3 be acceptable?

Comment: The arguments of `\fontsize` don't take dimensional expressions. They are numbers only. (The first one to determine the font size and second one sets the baseline height.) However, the implicit unit is pt as you rightly assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[2.3em]
  {}
  {\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.0]{2em}\MakeUppercase}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.6em]
  {}
  {\bfseries\contentslabel{2em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[6.9em]
  {}
  {\bfseries\contentslabel{2em}\itshape\space}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section*{\centerline{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
    \@mkboth
      {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
      {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
  }%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tables}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Design project background}
\subsection{Problem definition}
\subsubsection{Firmware code}

\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Comment: Note: `titletoc` destroys several KOMA features.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- wow, good to know! Which particular features are afflicted? And is this documented somewhere? (The `titlesec` docu, for instance, does not mention it.)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- btw: I realized that the OP does not require `scrartcl`. The other answer just used it and I followed blindly :) As my answer obviously works best with the standard classes I just changed it to `article`.

Comment: `titlesec` and `tocbibind` re bd with KOMA, `titletoc` seems to be fine. t least the few things i just tested.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Well, I used `titletoc` features only in this solution anyways. Thank you though! I'll keep in mind that `titlesec` and `tocbibind` are bad with the KOMA classes.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! Just a small thing though -- is there anyway I can change the "CONTENTS" title to Times New Roman (or the Latex version of it)? The code might as well be greek to me, since I'm not able to effectively decipher it enough to change the heading font.

Comment: @HardwareDoesItBetter, I did not update the output pic. The font actually was the serif font, not the sans-serif as in the old picture... If you want Times I would use it for the whole document, not just the toc title. For this you can use the `mathptmx` package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your indentation problem was, but I guess this might be what you were aiming for...!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
% Formatting of the TOC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{tables}
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{123}{\thepage}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip12pt}

\section{introduction}
\section{design...}
\subsection{problem...}
\subsection{needs...}


\appendix
\begingroup
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip12pt}
    \section{references}
    \section{relevant...}
    \section{bill...}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```